# RegEx matching for handling "" in a JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

Regex to handle the given input pattern involving double quotes

#### Input:

```
{
"adad":""Dip. Clinico E Di Ricerca Clinica-u.o.c.i Divisione ,gg677"","asd":"","dadd":"13213","Finance":[{"Financial_Contact_End_Date":""},{"Financial_Monthly_End_Date":""}]
}
```

I have tried this regex to handle the provided input.

```
a.replace("\"\"","\"").replaceAll("(:\",)",":\"\",").replaceAll("(:\"})", ":\"\"}")

a.replace("\"\"","\"").replaceAll("(:\",)",":\"\",").replaceAll("(:\"})", ":\"\"}")
```

#### Expected:

```
{
"adad":"Dip. Clinico E Di Ricerca Clinica-u.o.c.i Divisione ,gg677","asd":"","dadd":"13213","Finance":[{"Financial_Contact_End_Date":""},{"Financial_Monthly_End_Date":""}]
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: That is not json to begin with.

Comment: Consider using `JSON.parse()` to properly parse JSON.  If the input is not valid, it may help to work with its creator to make it valid, so you can simplify your code, and ensure its reliability.  See [this blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) for some tips (and limitations) of regular expressions.

Comment: The only problem is you can't just replace `""` with `"` because it could be a normal value `:"",` So, you have to qualify the match using the rules of parsing this structure. Lay out the rules first, regex later.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume it only surrounds *some* values then you can try a regex like  this

Find  `:""([^"]*)""`
Replace  `:"$1"`

https://regex101.com/r/mjewq0/1

Beware though, use this method, there is only one way to include a literal "
inside a string and that is to escape it `\"`

Answer (score 0):

This regex will solve your problem:

```
(("")(?!(,|})))|((?<!:)(""))
```

**explanation:**

This regex catches all the `""`s which does not ends with `'` or`}`

```
(("")(?!(,|})))
```

this regex catches all the `""`s which does not starts with `:`

```
((?<!:)(""))
```

**Theory:**

***Negative lookahead***

```
(?!...)
```

Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters.

eg:

> `/foo(?!bar)/`
>
> foobar **`foo`**bar

***Negative look-behind***

```
 (?<!...)
```

Ensures that the given pattern would not match and end at the current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed width. Does not consume characters.

eg:

> `/(?<!not )foo/`
>
> not foo but **`foo`**